# UIImageView width and UIScreen Width

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

This is my current scenario, I have a full width UIImageView when get the width using this `self.feedUiView.frame.size.width` it gives 584.0 but when I get the width of the device screen using this `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width` it gives me 375.0. How come the imageview is not the same with the screen device eventhough the imageview is full stretch on the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: get the frame in `viewDidAppear` and check

Comment: Maybe you have not used auto-layout/auto-resizing?

Comment: @avismara, I add  the feedUiView in storyboard.

Comment: @Bhavin - now it gives me the correct width of the feedUiView, may I know why in viewDidAppear it gives me the correct width but not in viewDidLoad

Comment: Yes. You should use autolayout/autoresizing to tell the runtime to resize itself. Otherwise, it will just pick the width of the imageview as specified in the storyboard and display.

Comment: set your image view clips to subview property to true from storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have set proper constraints.

And you should calculate this in `viewDidAppear` because it is called after view is appeared.

Viewdidload is called before it is appeared so it have your basic width which is given in interface builder.

Then it performs constraint during didload and resize according to constrains so it's final size you can know from `viewdidAppear` because in `viewdidload` it is just calculating constraints.

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

use autolayout. set feedUiView leading and trailing constraints from superview.

Comment: I already use autolayout for the constraint, when I get the frame size in viewDidAppear it gives me now the correct width

Answer (score 0):

This is because views that are built in storyboard keep their frame before `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You should check this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

With auto layout and constraint-based layout, views could continue to adjust their frames. viewWillLayoutSubviews & viewDidLayoutSubviews are correct places for checking and adjusting layout.

Documentation for viewDidlayoutSubviews can be checked here -
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 0):

Once I have the same issue. Because I use the launch image, and only set the launch image for 5S and 6S, not for the 6P size. Once I add the launch image for the 6P size, the issue was gone.

-Good Luck.